# Cookie detection in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the best way to implement cookie detection in rails 3.2?

I'd like to redirect user to special action if cookies are disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the session_id that rails stores automatically

```
redirect_to root_path unless cookies["_session_id"]
```